# ¿Se puede heredar de una clase Jframe form en una java class implementando Runnable?

Tags: java, netbeans, hilos, herencia

Tengo este codigo en el source del Jframe forms:

public class Interface extends javax.swing.JFrame{

```
Bus1 objRunnable = new Bus1();
Thread hiloR = new Thread(objRunnable);
public DefaultListModel modelo = new DefaultListModel();
public ArrayList<String> paradasBus = new ArrayList<>();

int z = 0;

public Interface() {
    initComponents();
    ListaParadas.setModel(modelo);
}

private void btnIniciar1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    hiloR.start();
}
```

En un paquete en el mismo proyecto tengo una javaclass llamada Bus1:

public class Bus1 extends PerifericaL1.Interface implements Runnable{

```
public boolean activo = true;
Random img = new Random();
Random tiem = new Random();
int i = 0;
int tiempo = 0;
int c = 0;


@Override
public void run() {
    i = 1;
    while (activo == true) {
        tiempo = tiem.nextInt(2000);
        if (i == 1) {
            
            PerifericaL1.Interface.uno.setLocation(190, 330);
            
            i++;
            try {
                sleep(Tiempo);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            c++;
        }

        try {
            sleep(Tiempo);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

}

a la hora de ejecutarlo me tira un error pero cuando quito el extends de la clase Jframe, me ejectuta normal.
Hay una forma que pueda heredad los atributos de la clase Jframe para ser llamados desde la java class?

Comment: Muy recomendable que primero leas sobre [concurrencia](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) en la documentación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí, es posible heredar de una clase JFrame en una clase Java que implementa la interfaz Runnable. Sin embargo, es importante tener en cuenta que la interfaz Runnable es utilizada para ejecutar código en un hilo (thread) separado, mientras que JFrame es utilizado para crear ventanas de aplicaciones de escritorio.

Por lo general, se recomienda no mezclar la lógica de una aplicación de escritorio con la lógica de un hilo separado, ya que puede resultar en código confuso y difícil de mantener. Si deseas utilizar un hilo separado en tu aplicación de escritorio, es mejor crear una clase que implemente la interfaz Runnable y utilizarla de manera independiente, sin heredar de JFrame.

Si aún deseas heredar de JFrame y utilizar la interfaz Runnable, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
public class MiVentana extends JFrame implements Runnable {
  // Constructor
  public MiVentana() {
    // Inicializa la ventana aquí
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    // Escribe aquí el código que se ejecutará en el hilo separado
  }
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver tu duda. Si necesitas más ayuda, no dudes en preguntar. Estoy a tu disposición para ayudarte.